# CloudFlare failed to purge dynamic content to a blog post

Tags: cloudflare

I run my blog that linked with Cloudflare when I create a new post I don't see the current post that affected my site. I tried many methods that I learned from sites like trying to use a page rule to bypass Cloudflare cache but it didn't work. Also, I turn it off auto minify js, CSS, and Html still does not work. my blog still shows the oldest post that is from since 5 days ago.  When you log in WordPress dashboard panel you will see the current posts but for the normal visit will see the cached posts that remain static all time

here is my Cloudflare setting

**Page Rules Settings**
[image: page Rules Settings]

**Page Speed Settings**
[image: Page Speed Settings]

**Page Caching Settings**
[image: Page Caching Settings]

I need your help from everybody who knows about this problem and how we can solve it
Thanks....!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this problem because all performance is managed by Ezoic. I tried to purge everything on Ezoic and all things are working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the site now, looks like you have maybe disabled Cloudflare? I'm seeing the latest posts, and there are no Cloudflare response headers coming back.

For troubleshooting caching issues, one of the most useful things you can do is to inspect the response headers (using Chrome Dev Tools or similar 'Network' tab). First step is to identify which request is responsible for the cached content (a document, or an AJAX call, etc.)

From there, you can look at the response headers to see why it is behaving this way, specifically you'll want to check the `Cache-Control` and `CF-Cache-Status` header. More info here - https://developers.cloudflare.com/cache/about/default-cache-behavior